# How to fix a List<> that become null inside OnCreateView()

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase realtime-database and put it on a CardView inside a RecyclerView inside a Fragment.

But the Fragment shown is blank white with no error. I retrieve the data inside OnCreate method and add it into a List.

While debugging the application, found out that even after assigning the retrieved data inside the `onCreate` method, the list is still NULL inside the `onCreateView` method.

Fragment Dashboard List Class:

```
public class fragment_dashboard_list extends Fragment {

    List<ibu> ibu_ibu;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef ;
    String a;

    public fragment_dashboard_list() {}
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ibu_ibu = new ArrayList<>();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("Guardian");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    ibu value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ibu.class);
                    ibu ibu_val = new ibu();

                    String alamat = value.getAlamat();
                    String foto = value.getFoto();
                    String hp = value.getHp();
                    String ktp = value.getKtp();
                    String nama = value.getNama();
                    String privilege = value.getPrivilege();
                    String ttl = value.getTtl();

                    ibu_val.setAlamat(alamat);
                    ibu_val.setFoto(foto);
                    ibu_val.setHp(hp);
                    ibu_val.setKtp(ktp);
                    ibu_val.setNama(nama);
                    ibu_val.setPrivilege(privilege);
                    ibu_val.setTtl(ttl);

                    // Here the List ibu_ibu is not NULL
                    ibu_ibu.add(ibu_val);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("Hello", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_list, container, false);

        RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_recycler_view);

        //Here the List ibu_ibu is null
        adapter_list_ibu myAdapter = new adapter_list_ibu(ibu_ibu);
        LinearLayoutManager LinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        myrv.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager);
        myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I expected the List to be not NULL inside `OnCreateView` so the Fragment wont Blank

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase APIs are asynchronous, which means that `onDataChange()` method returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available.

Because that method returns immediately, your `ibu_val` list that you're trying to use it outside the `onDataChange()` method, will not have been populated from the callback yet and that's why is always empty.

Basically, you're trying to use a value of variable synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea, you should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to notify the adapter once you got all elements from the database using:

```
myrv.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

So add this line of code right after where the for loop ends.

If you intent to use that list outside the callback, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.